# Show the jQuery dialog after X seconds of page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Using jQuery 1.7.1, I want to show a dialog box to the user for both these circumstances...

1. Approximately after 15 seconds when the page has finished loading if no user interaction has been done i.e. page scroll, link click. The dialog box should appear.
2. If after say 10 seconds an interaction (page scroll / form field click) no further action has been done and the user is still on the same page. The dialog box should appear.

---

The purpose of this is to show a 'do you need any help / feedback' dialog to a user if they are still on the same page for a number of seconds and haven't scrolled or have scrolled and not interacted on the page i.e. clicked a link / form field.

In the dialog i will show a 'No help needed' link which needs to hide the dialog and stop it opening again during the session. So if this link is clicked the dialog and counter must be stopped for the remainder of that php session.

Comment: Look at jQuery ui. Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: I believe you have misstagged PHP, there is nothing related here.

Comment: @DarylGill A session is PHP. But he could use a cookie or sessionStorage instead.

Comment: @RichardA, its something new that im looking into, would prefer a php session but perhaps it might have to be a cookie.

Comment: @DarylGill planning to use PHP for a session not for the scripting.

Comment: @dg85 Tbh, `sessionStorage` is MUCH easier to use for this. The downside however is that it's HTML5 and isn't supported in IE 7 and older if you aim for that.

Comment: @RichardA, ive tried searching applying a delay to dialogue after scroll but can all i seem to get is loads of info about hiding scrollbars from the dialogue. Im focusing on IE8+, anyone on IE7 seriously needs an upgrade as ie7 wont even show animated gifs.

Comment: Could someone please point me in the right direction as im hitting a wall with this. And/or any similar code would be a big help.

Comment: @dg85 I'm working on an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [jQuery UI's modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) and sessionStorage.

Here is an example of what you might look for:

```
function showHelpModal()
{
    // Open the dialog and reset the timer
    $('#mymodal').dialog('open');
    timeoutStarted = false;
}

var t; // Timeout variable
var timeout = 1500; // Timeout in milliseconds
var fakeSessionStorage = {}; // The fake sessionStorage, don't use this in your real code

$(document).ready(function()
{   
    // Initialize the dialog
    $('#mymodal').dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Don't remind me": function()
            {
                fakeSessionStorage.stopReminding = true;
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },

            "Yes, please": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    // Set default reminder value
    if(!fakeSessionStorage.stopReminding)
        fakeSessionStorage.stopReminding = false;

    // On scroll...
    $(document).scroll(function()
    {        
        // If the user doesn't want to be reminded, return false
        if(fakeSessionStorage.stopReminding)
        {
            console.log("Will not remind again");
            return false;
        }

        // Start the timer and prevent it from firing while busy
        timeoutStarted = true;
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(showHelpModal, timeout);
    });
});
```

And a working example at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ev8h/2/)

Please mind you that sessionStorage doesn't work on JSfiddle, so I used a object called `fakeSessionStorage` to cover for that.

Also, sessionStorage doesn't work in Internet Explorer 7 or earlier.

**[edit]**
I had the wrong fiddle linked, fixed that.

**[edit 2]**
Having the `timeoutStarted` variable there was apparently the problem. I thought it was a neccessary thing but it was doing more bad than good.

Comment: been looking at this again and on the jsfiddle example its loads straight away after the scrolling has stopped and not after they timeout which i thought by looking at the code it should be. Whether this is also a similar issue... Also fires when scrolling (either when clicking the scrollbar arrow buttons or grabing the slider bar and changing direction in one moment without a pause. See the JSfiddle as per your example. Can you suggest any edit for this?

Comment: @DavidG Look at my updated answer for the new code and an explaination why. This should do what you need.

Comment: ive tried removing the 'timeoutStarted' variable from the previous jsfiddle however but now the dialog doesn't load. Tried to see your updates jsfiddle but the link appears to be wrong as getting an 'Error 404' message... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DaBananaboat/3ev8h/2/)

Comment: @DavidG Fixed the link. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there any way of also including a check to see when the mouse cursor has stopped moving as well as the page scroll? ... So the dialog appears after X seconds of both the page stopped scrolling AND mouse moving

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, add a `.mousemove()` event to the document, let it clear and set a timeout every time the mouse moves. When not moving, the timeout should expire and then you can make it do what you want it to do.